# ClassNotFoundException running simple applets

Tags: java, applet

I wrote http://pastebin.com/EwShF3YS for school;   It's a simple java applet with a GUI pair of eyes that watches the cursor as it moves.  It runs well in a compiler (NetBeans 7.4) , but for the life of me I'm having difficulty understanding why it doesn't run in a browser.  I'm getting ClassNotFound exceptions.   All the reading I've been doing suggests that a .class file isn't required because it's an applet, the browser should generate one at runtime.  And if a class is required, how come NetBeans can run it without one?

The HTML file is stored in the same directory as the .java - and it's real simple:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>WatchMe</title>
</head>
<body>
<applet code="WatchMe.class" width="300" height="200">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried a variety of different things, different browsers, setting classpath; opening it on different computers.  The result is always the same, ClassNotFound exception.  The internet research I've been doing yields mostly unproductive answers, such as one person who completely reloaded his PC.  I've noticed that if I fully qualify the path to WatchMe.class I get a hang/blank browser page.  I'm completely out of ideas, so any suggestions or advice is welcome.

Comment: Did your research go so far as reading the dozen exact same questions with answers in the **Related** side bar of this question on this same site?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the compiled `WatchMe.class` in the same directory as HTML File. Having the .java file is not enough and no the browser will not compile anything for you. It will just run the .class file using the JRE.

Answer (score 0):

> All the reading I've been doing suggests that a .class file isn't required because it's an applet, the browser should generate one at runtime.

This is incorrect.  You must provide either a ".class" file, or JAR files containing ".class" files for the browser to fetch.

A web browser's Java plugin is not capable of compiling Java code.  If you've found a resource that tells you otherwise, it is WRONG.  (I'd be interested to see concrete examples of this misinformation!  Can you post the URLs?)

It is possible that your confusion arises from reading material on Javascript and thinking that it applies to Java.  Don't!!  They are very different languages ... and material on one does not apply to the other.

---

OK so why is your example not working?

It is hard to say, but the most likely reasons are:

- you've used the wrong name or path in the "code" attribute,
- you need a "codebase" attribute to allow the browser to map the ".class" name to the correct URL for downloading it,
- your code depends on other classes (that are not in the browser plugin's class library), or
- it is a bytecode version issue; i.e. you have compiled your applet with a later version of Java than is supported by the browser.

Try looking in the browser's Java console for the complete error message and stacktrace for the exception.

Try looking at the server-side HTTP logs to see what files that the client is attempting to fetch ... and what the server's response is.

Comment: I apologize,  I walked away from it for a while and came back in a day, cracked the books, figured it out.  It truly was PEBKAC,  somehow I just didn't realize that when NetBeans compiles, it generates a .class file, and was putting that file in a completely different directory then src.   The solution is to just put the HTML in the same directory as the .class.  I'd apologize and promise not to be stupid again, but let's be honest, I WILL be stupid again.  Best I can offer is to try not to make the same mistake twice.